# How to label duplicate geometric features avoiding text overlap for more than 16 duplicates?

Tags: qgis, labeling

It seems that the strategy of using the increase the distance of the label placement together with use callout lines to connect the labels to the features, only works with less than 17 duplicate values. Above 17 records they overlap again as shown in the attached screenshot. Is there any alternative to solve this casuistic?

[image]

Comment: It might be a bit of an obvious question, but have you tried increasing the distance even more? It seems that the seventh value should logically be displayed at the very top or at the very bottom and for some reason it's overlapping the top right one.

Comment: Confirmed that increasing the distance is not the solution. With less than 17 duplicates, partially solved by modifying the Placement Mode option to Point around, but after 16 duplicates the problem persists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your points are exactly the same, what you can do is the following (if not, the same approach can be taken by adapting the geometric criterion).

Collect all 'VALUETXT' for points which intersect and display one label as the list of this list.

`array_to_string(array_prepend(overlay_intersects('points',text),"text"))`

This generates a list like: 'text1,text2,text3,text4,text5'

Make sure the `Never Overlap` is configured so that only one of the overlapping points generates a label.

And then ask for the Label to be wraped around the ',' separator:

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you want to sort labels, you can use:

`array_to_string(     array_sort(array_prepend(overlay_intersects('points',text),"text")))`